# Regex and carriage returns

Tags: php, regex

I'm working through a weird problem with carriage returns in a web form causing confusion in my regex statements.  I'm new to regex, so please forgive any obtuse questions.

When my form sends data input from a text area, the following functions are used to turn any qualifying string into a hyperlink:

```
function make_links_clickable($message)
    {
    return preg_replace('!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $message);
    }
function make_links_clickable2($message)
    {
    return preg_replace('!(www\.)?[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,3}(\.?[a-z]{2,3})?)!i', '<a href="http://$0" target="_blank">$0</a>', $message);
    }
$message = make_links_clickable2($message);
```

The problem seems to be in the second function.  When I use these functions, the output looks like this:

```
www.google.com
http://www.google.com
nwww.google.com
http://www.google.com
```

The third output has an 'n' at the beginning (and its hyperlink is also messed), which seems to be from the carriage return.  No idea how this is happening.

Comment: Does the Form you are using have PUT or GET?

Comment: @Leptonator do you mean PUT or POST (there's a difference)? Anyway how do you think this could matter?

Comment: Yes - I don't think the issue is how you do carriage return - but if press enter to submit a form..

Comment: The problem is `(www\.)?`... don't have a good solution yet though...

Comment: `а-яА-Я`? No. At least if that's a latin `a` you'll get much more than you think in there. Also don't use two replaces. That will break. Do it in one pass.

Comment: What is the original content of $message?

Comment: The original message is identical to the output shown above except tht the third line reads 'www.google.com'.  FOr whatever reason, the second function sees something in the carriage return (probably \n) and it gets messed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really into it, but is it possible that you have to escape the backslash twice like:

```
'!(www\\.)?[a-z0-9\-] etc.
```

This might be the problem.

Greetings